# Need to have Watermark on each image in preview and even after downloading in Laravel PHP script

Tags: php, laravel, image, watermark

I have a site where I use Laravel. It's for stock images, and when each image is previewed there's a watermark in the corner.

However, when I download the image the watermark is not on the image.

It currently only works when previewing the image.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Image::make($temp.$preview)
    ->insert('public/img/watermark.png','bottom-left')
    ->save($temp.$preview)
    ->destroy();
```